# How do you pass a variable from a link to a form?

Tags: php, html, url, variables

If I have a file, `firstfile.html`, which has a hyperlink in it to :
`secondfile.php?type=2&subcategory=4`

How do I then extract that in the code in `secondfile.php`, using html or php?

I basically want some inputs in a form to be auto-filled with the information passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs on external source variables:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

In your particular situation, you'd use `$_GET['type']` or `$_REQUEST['type']`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable.

More specifically here's the code I would use to populate a text field:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($_GET['type'])) {echo(htmlspecialchars($_GET['type']));} ?>"/>
```

Comment: prefer `<?=`: `<?=htmlspecialchars(filter_input(INPUT_GET,'type'))?>` (I know some heretics disable it; fortunately it's always enabled in PHP5.4)

Comment: Right, thanks for the reply.
But wouldn't it be enough to just use:
value="<?php{echo(htmlspecialchars($_GET['type']));} ?>"

Comment: @DLA, no, this would display a warning when `$_GET['type']` is not set

Comment: If the variable is not passed (e.g. you visit `secondfile.php` without any `?type=abcd`), then you might see the following error message inside the text field instead: `Notice: Undefined index: type in /blah/blah/blah.php on line 1 `

Comment: If you are sure that shorthand is enabled on all the server that may ever want to run your code on, please go ahead and use it. I wouldn't do that until I was absolutely sure, though.

Comment: @Umang make sure PHP is installed too ;) More seriously, this is enabled by default in PHP, so you should assume that it is enabled. And for cases where it's not, `php_value short_open_tag 1` and you are safe.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks, I learned something new! Not that I code much PHP nowadays, but I will remember this should I ever need to.